# C# Architectural Design Short-comings

Tags: c#, architecture

I have a code framework I use in C# that is build on the concept of layers:

- At the bottom layer, we have the data layer (database, remote service, etc).
- Right above that is the Access Layer (code to interact with the data layer).
- Right above that is the persistence layer. (Code to translate and transform  data between the application logic and the data layers requirements, as well as handle any compounding of method calls into the access for complex object graphs and operations.)
- Then finally, the process layer (code with the general application logic.)

Each layer communicates only with the layer immediately above it or below it. So the general application flow is

```
Processor -> Peristence -> Access -> Data
Data -> Access -> Persistence -> Processor
```

The general concept is that, the processor acts as a general representation of a single process containing  1 or more steps. It is called independently by the executing code. But a process could easily become a step for another larger process.

Where I am running into a problem (or really a potential problem) is that, when I have a process that contains 1 or more child processes, or the process uses persistence and it has any child process using the persistence layer, I have no way of opening a single DB connection for both processes to use. Each process would instantiate and open its own connection. For example, here is an actual code snippet:

```
var contactProcessor = new SelectContactProcessor();
var contact = contactProcessor.GetContact(contactId);
if (contact == null)
    throw new Exception("Unable to locate contact");
viewModel.DisplayName = contact.DisplayName;
viewModel.City = contact.City;
viewModel.State = contact.State;

var processor = new PresentCurrentSurveyProcessor();
var data = processor.GetSurveyData();
if (data == null)
   throw new Exception("Unable to locate survey");
viewModel.SurveyId = data.ID;
viewModel.SurveyName = data.SurveyName;
viewModel.StartDate = data.StartDate.ToShortDateString();
viewModel.EndDate = data.EndDate.ToShortDateString();
viewModel.Questions = data.Questions;
return viewModel;
```

So in this example, the SelectContactProcessor is going to instantiate a Peristence layer which will connection to the Db, and the PersentCurrentSurveyProcessor will also instantiate a different persistence object which will also connect to the same Db. But they wont share connections and can't execute transactionally (if desired) due to this architecture.

While I have a few things in mind, I am curious to see what solutions others may see to this issue that I would overlook. I don't want ultimately break my rule about layers only interacting with their immediate neighbor.

Comment: Or second glance I should point out that this architecture is my own doing and the "Short Comings" in the title is a reference to my own solution's short comings and in no way meant to be a reflection of C# itself.

Comment: Create a TransactionContext object which can be optionally passed into your persistence layer calls.  This object will contain whatever information is necessary to use an existing connection.  If it is passed in, the persistence layer will use it, if not, the persistence layer will create one and pass it back for later potential use.  In order to keep connection details in the Access layer, this could be something as simple as a token that the Access layer can use to look up an existing transaction. Adds some bookkeeping code, but keeps your processing layer from caring about the access layer.

Comment: @debugger, I was thinking about something along a similar line. Sort of like using(Transaction) { processors galore }

Comment: My one concern with this is that effectively every Processor, PersistenceObject, and AccessLayer would have to update to pass along an optionally present Transaction Context. I am not sure that that is necessarily a major hurdle with new code though (just an inconvenience with existing code.)

Comment: You can add it, as needed, to persistence object's that require it.  Should not be necessary to do a "change everything" update.

Comment: I think the processor needs to allow for injection as well though, because a processor can simultaneously be used on its own, and as a sub step of another processor.

Comment: Well, first of all, you have to understand that creating two connections isn't necessary a bad thing, since .NET uses connection pooling.  The Transaction issue can be solved by enlisting in a DTC transaction, however this won't perform as well as local transaction.  The point being, is its possible to support transactions with multiple connections, it just won't be as efficient.  If efficiency is your concern, then you will have to develop a cross cutting concern for this.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch while the pool will keep a reference to the underlying connection, wouldn't the code still have the overhead of opening and closing the connection?

Comment: @Goblyn27 - no, that's the point of the pool, it keeps connections open.

Comment: @Goblyn27 Do you mean UnitOfWork pattern by mentioning  TransactionContext?

Comment: I don't know. I think I may be and not realizing it. I have to read up on the pattern a bit more. I am only very mildly familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

I will expand here a little on my comment. What I propose (and what @Goblyn27 evidently suggested) is to add an object, that will contain an instance of open connection and methods you need to work with it (start / commit transactions for example).

In web applications I develop I usually put such object into DI container since I need only one instance of it per request. It is then injected by DI into any service in a need of it.

This object also controls nested transaction use (many DBs don't support that so I keep a stack of `startTransaction()` calls, poped by each 'commit()' and actually commit only when this stack is empty.

Your application is a little bit different, but you can try to utilize the same way.

I would recommend the use of some simple DI container instead of passing globals around, however.